Exercise 1.1.7 from Tao-Vu's Additive Combinatorics
The exercise is the following:

Consider a non-empty subset $A$ of a finite additive group $Z$. Show that there exists a subset $\{v_1, \dots, v_d\}$ of $Z$ with $d = O(\log\frac{\lvert Z \rvert}{\lvert A \rvert} + \log \log (10 + \lvert Z \rvert))$ such that $A + [0,1]^d \cdot (v_1, \dots, v_d) = Z$.

I have already solved the previous exercise, which has almost the same statement, except that $d = O(\log\frac{\lvert Z \rvert}{\lvert A \rvert})$ and the resulting sum-set needs to only be as big as $\frac{\lvert Z \rvert}{2}$.
My approach for that was to iteratively choose some element $v_k \in Z$, such that $A_k := A + [0,1]^k \cdot (v_1, \dots, v_k)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:one}
\lvert A_k \rvert \geq \lvert A_{k-1} \rvert \left(2 - \frac{\lvert A_{k-1}\rvert}{\lvert Z \rvert}\right),
\end{equation}
where $A_0 := A$. Such an element is guaranteed to exist by a previous exercise. One can then define $d$ to be the smallest integer for which $\lvert A_d \rvert \geq \lvert Z \rvert / 2$ and show the desired size of $d$ by playing with the inequality above with $k=d-1$.
This approach could in principle also work for the follow-up task. Equation \eqref{eq:one} implies that the sets increase in size, until $A_k = Z$. So just let $d$ be the smallest integer for which this happens. This is where I get stuck. Using $d-1$ as above doesn't seem to work, because we don't have a multplicative relation like $\lvert A_{d-1} \rvert < \lvert Z \rvert / 2$ anymore; only $\lvert A_{d-1} \rvert < \lvert Z \rvert - 1$, which I've tried but yields an extremely bad bound on $d$.
Is there a simple way out of this that I'm just not seeing, or do I maybe need to derive a different relation than \eqref{eq:one}? Also, I don't see where the $\log\log(10 + \lvert Z \rvert)$ should come from. Any hints would be appreciated.

Let me first sum up what your construction gives -

We know that after $d_{1}=O\left(\log\frac{\vert A\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\right)$ steps, $\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

In each step, we have by $\left(1\right)$ $$ \vert A_{k+1}\vert\ge\vert A_{k}\vert\left(2-\frac{\vert A_{k}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\right)$$ or after completing the square $$1-\frac{\vert A_{k+1}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\le\left(1-\frac{\vert A_{k}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\right)^{2}\;\;\;\left(2\right).$$


We now continue with your construction - Since $\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\ge\frac{1}{2}$, we get $1-\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\le\frac{1}{2}$. Plug into $\left(2\right)$ $$1-\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}+1}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\le\left(1-\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\right)^{2}\le2^{-2}$$ and hence, after $d_{2}$ iterations $$1-\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}+d_{2}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}\le2^{-2^{d_{2}}}.$$ From this, we get that after $d_{2}=O\left(\log\log\vert Z\vert\right)$ steps $$1-\frac{\vert A_{d_{1}+d_{2}}\vert}{\vert Z\vert}<\frac{1}{\vert Z\vert}$$ or $$\vert A_{d_{1}+d_{2}}\vert>\vert Z\vert-1$$ so we must have $A_{d_{1}+d_{2}}=Z$. This was done in a total of $$d:=d_{1}+d_{2}=O\left(\log\frac{\vert A\vert}{\vert Z\vert}+\log\log\vert Z\vert\right)$$ steps, as needed.

That is very elegant, thank you! $(2)$ was actually the form that the original inequality from the previous exercise was given in. I naively thought that simplifying it would make things easier.

@ndieck I'm glad I could help. The main point is that $(2)$ is well-suited for creating a kind of 'multiplicative decreasing iteration law' which I assume is what caused you the difficulty.

The main issue was that I didn't know which direction to explore because I couldn't see the overall picture, if that makes sense. Which probably comes down to a lack of experience solving these exercises.
